# Getting 404 Error when trying to share from my custom iOS app with Google+

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-status-code-404, share, google-plus

I installed the google+ SDK for iOS and implemented the share function:

```
- (void)customUIASView:(CustomUIASView *)customUIASView didClickGoogle:(UIButton *)sender{

    static NSString * const kClientId = @"122385832599-2mcvobo565un3ab7d6d06m6fjemocto9.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    share = [[GPPShare alloc] initWithClientID:kClientId];
    share.delegate = self;
    [[[[share shareDialog]
       setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:myUrl]]
      setPrefillText:oPin.sName] open];

}
```

And everything works fine, no errors in the console, but when safari mobile is opened with this link (which works fine for all desktop browsers), I got the 404 error!

https://plus.google.com/share?client_id=122385832599-2mcvobo565un3ab7d6d06m6fjemocto9.apps.googleusercontent.com&continue=com.pinstyle.pinstyle%3A%2F%2Fshare%2F&text=NEU%20H%26M%20Divided%20Grey%20blogger%20Trend%20urban%20Leder%20Biker%20Jacke%20Nieten%2034%20S%20XS%2036&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpinboard.maryme.lan.s3.amazonaws.com%2F1%2F25607-neuhmdividedgreybloggertrendurbanlederbikerjackenieten34sxs36.jpg&bundle_id=com.pinstyle.pinstyle&gpsdk=1.0.0

Someone had the same error:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-plus-developers/ZSCxGNTqRJY/jidPJ076BfYJ

but the solution was changing the BundleID to another one with at least one dot. My bundleId already have two dots, so I don´t know what to do. Does anyone have any clue of how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: is your problem solved.I am also facing the same problem . please let me kno how you fix this.

Comment: no, I already reported it to the google support center but they don´t answer. could you please give one point to the question? so it won´t get closed...

Comment: you can also report the issue in the google center so it gets more priority: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=457

Comment: I have voted up the question and also added a comment, lets hope for the best.

Comment: Did anybody get the solution?

Comment: No, not yet! I will post the solution when I find one

Comment: Same issue here. No solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like bundle id authentication error, if you changed the bundle id to another without a corresponding change in the apps service on google server,you should get this error.

so,try to revise your bundle id and modify it to the one you entered on Google server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your bundle id in the Google Developer console is written properly. Keep in mind it's **case sensitive**! This was my problem...